# Does the convergence of product imply convergence of sum?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, infinite-product

> Does the convergence of a product imply the convergence of a sum?
>
> $$\prod_{n=0}^\infty(1+a_n)<M_1\implies\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n<M_2$$

I don't know any properties determinable from the fact that the product converges to say anything about the sum.

---

If so, what about the other way around?

Comment: I think this is correct. I saw a proof in a book that uses the $\ln$ function (of course it should, but I don't know how exactly).

Answer (score 5):

This implication is not true. Let $a_{2n}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}, a_{2n+1}=\frac{-1}{\sqrt{n}+1}$.  Focusing on consecutive terms, we see $a_{2n}+a_{2n+1}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}+\frac{-1}{\sqrt{n}+1}=\frac{1}{n+\sqrt{n}}$ and $(1+a_{2n})\cdot (1+a_{2n+1})=(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})(1+\frac{-1}{\sqrt{n}+1})=1$. Then clearly the relevant infinite product tends to $1$, but the series diverges.

A simple implication that is true is the following: $\prod_{n=0}^{\infty} (1+|a_{n}|)$ converges $\Rightarrow$ $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|a_{n}|$ converges $\Rightarrow$ $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}$ converges because it converges absolutely. (This follows immediately from expanding the terms in the partial products.)

More generally, a well-known result is the following: $\prod_{n=0}^{\infty}(1+a_{n})$ converges absolutely if and only if $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}$ converges absolutely. This is Theorem $6$ of Chapter $5$ in Ahlfors' classic complex analysis text.

Comment: On the other hand, one often says that a product 'diverges'  if it 'converges' to $0$. Of course this is because $\mathbb R^+$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$ under $\log$ - so $0$ corresponds to $-\infty$...

Comment: I agree with peterag, most contexts have $\prod$ diverges if it goes to $0$.  But anyways, thanks for the answer.  I'd like a more rigorous proof though please.  More explanation would be nice.

Comment: Oops, sorry! I was being silly.  I corrected the answer.